# A Plot Graph .NET WindowsForm Component Free

Tags: c#, .net, math, graph, plot

I'm searching for a plot .NET component to plot a 2D line chart, given an array of data. It will be used with WindowsForm (C#) and It will be very helpful if it could be freeware. It is for a scientific application.
This is my first asked question in stackoverflow, and excuse me for my terrible English written.

Comment: Have you checked CodeProject.com?

Comment: Have you looked at the Microsoft .NET Chart Controls?  Summary of what you can get is at http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/10/free-winform-and-aspnet-chart-controls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en) is the way to go.

Maybe you should take a look into [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [zedgraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) ?